# Change Outlook's default calendar to iCloud (meeting requests end up in wrong calendar)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, meeting-request, icloud

Following scenario: I've got a main computer (Windows 7, Office 2010) which is being used to manage contacts, meetings, etc. using Outlook. Now I've added an iPad and an iPhone to sync using iCloud. I moved all appointments and contacts from the old PST file to the iCloud file. All the data syncs nicely.

The email account I'm using in Outlook is an IMAP account which opens up another data file which brings us to a total of three data files in Outlook's side bar.

The problem: When one of our clients sends us meeting requests via email they show up in the IMAP's inbox. When we open them up they automatically get added to Outlook's default calendar (the one in the original PST). Is there any chance not to add them to that calendar but the iCloud one? Basically we could completely get rid of the original PST since we don't use it at all anymore but the settings do not allow me to remove this PST file and set the iCloud one as default.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Whenever I accept an Outlook meeting request it goes to the default Outlook calendar instead of the iCloud Outlook calendar, which is really annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up using a Microsoft Live account which integrates kinda nicely into Outlook and works as an Exchange account on the iOS devices, IIRC. It does the trick, but this solution seems to be way slower.

Comment: Same issue for me, whenever someone finds an answer please reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with two PSTs a couple of years ago and the solution was to set up a rule to move the invite (when it arrives) immediately out of the original PST and into a folder inside the other (iCloud) PST.

If you now open the invite from the new location, you should find that any responses should now go into the calendar within that PST and not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way of changing Outlook's default to use the iCloud calendar for meeting requests (I think that would be the ideal solution if Outlook supported it), but I found a work around that seems to work OK for me.

When you've selected the meeting request in Outlook you should see the "Reply using iCloud" button on the toolbar.  Click this and choose Accept then your meeting will be added to your iCloud calendar, which should sync to your iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Your original invitation from Outlook will end up in the local calendar on your computer.

You will see, when using iCloud that there is also an iCloud calendar. Simply click on the invitation in the calendar once (the one that you have just accepted via email and which shows up in your local calendar). Then drag the invitation to the left side of the screen where you see iCloud calendar.

The invitation should now have been moved from the local one to the iCloud one.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the user wants this to happen automatically (i.e., *not* requiring manual action for each one) — or, better yet, to go *directly* to iCloud, so he can remove the local calendar.